# How to get qt4 runtime libraries

Tags: qt, shared-libraries

The latest (stretch) image has dropped all qt4 libraries and has qt5 libraries instead.

But I still have A LOT of qt4 software. I have searched the web but every hit tells me how to install the qt4 **development environment**. I don't want that. I want to have all the old "/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQtGui.so.4" etc. **libraries** back.

I assume (hope!) there is an apt-get install 'rune' but I don't know the magic word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4
```

worked for me.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I have found no easy way to do this. For now I have downloaded all qt4 libraries from an old Pi image and then uploaded them to a new pi. (My SSH refuses to write direct to /usr/lib) Next sudo copy them to /usr/lib in the right place with the right (multi depth) paths and library names. As last action I have to run ldconfig... for each new directory.

I still believe there must be a better way to do this!